# How to use addHeaderView to add a simple ImageView to a ListView

Tags: android, listview, imageview

My target is simple. I want to add a "Red Rectangle" as a *headerview* to a `ListView`.
so I create a simple activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String[] adapterData = new String[] { "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", 
            "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola"}; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lv;
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        LayoutInflater lf;
        View headerView;
        lf = this.getLayoutInflater();
        headerView = (View)lf.inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);

        lv.addHeaderView(headerView, null, false);

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, adapterData)); 
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"
        android:paddingRight="20dip"
        android:divider="#0000"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />
```

list_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:minHeight="40dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
/>
```

most important, header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:background="#F00"/>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Nothing is displayed.

Can any give some suggestions on this? Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Here is the solution -- > http://stackoverflow.com/a/34557372/542532

Answer (score 16):

Old question, but I just copied it and run it and indeed the red doesn't show up.

You're missing one simple thing: **Regardless of how you call `inflate` you always<sup>1</sup> have to pass a parent view (second param) so that it can figure out which `LayoutParams` subclass to instantiate.**
*<sup>1</sup>: there are always<sup>1</sup> exceptions*

> .inflate(R.layout.header, ***lv***, false)

For more on the subject I highly suggest: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/ (worth reading even a few times)

Your full code modified (xml files can stay as is):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String[] ADAPTER_DATA = {
            "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola"
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, list, false);

        list.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, ADAPTER_DATA));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue! The problem in my case was just the missign "false" parameter in         View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, list, false); !

Comment: The inflated header view may be bare-bone, how can I add values to the sub-views in the layout (such as texts, etc.) at runtime?

Answer (score 13):

This is how I add a header:

```
    View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.header, null);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    lv.addHeaderView(view);
```

Comment: I think the "inflate" action is equivalent, thanks very much, but it didn't help.

Comment: @laura  how can get onClick on header items?

Answer (score 2):

Check this, I have get it working right now:

```
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View headerView = (View) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.header, lv, false);
```

Just send listview to the second param of the inflate method :)

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the header view in a separated xml file. Then, inflate it in to a View instance and set it to ListView.

```
View view = ... (inflate the view from xml file)
listview.addHeaderView(view)
```

You must call addHeaderView before setAdapter to the listview.

Comment: yes, just as the code I post, I declare header.xml as a seperated xml file. and I call addHeaderView before setAdapter to the listview.

Comment: Let take a look at http://www.samcoles.co.uk/mobile/android-listactivity-with-a-header-or-footer/. Hope this helps.