# Android list view inside a scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have an android layout which has a `scrollView` with a number of elements with in it. At the bottom of the `scrollView` I have a `listView` which is then populated by an adapter.

The problem that I am experiencing, is that android is excluding the `listView` from the `scrollView` as the `scrollView` already has a scroll-able function.  I want the `listView` to be as long as the content is and for the master scroll view to be scroll-able.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Here is my main layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="top" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I then programmatically add my components to the linearlayour with the id: `foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments`.  Below is one of the views that is loaded into that linearlayout. This is the one giving me trouble with the scrolls.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/fragment_dds_review_textView_label"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Reviews:"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/fragment_dds_review_listView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My adapter then fills up this list view.

Here is an image from the android hierarchy viewer when I click on the master scrollView:

[image: Android List View inside a scroll view]

As you can see, it is excluding the reviews listView.

I should be able to scroll the page down and see 8 reviews, but instead it only shows me those 3, and I can scroll on the tiny part where the reviews are. I want a global page scroll

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813296/non-scrollable-listview-inside-scrollview try this

Comment: i get a solution on : http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/12/listview-into-scrollview-in-android.html

Comment: Here it is. You can find full descriptive information:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116381/listview-without-scrollbar-to-use-in-a-scrollview/20116560#20116560

Comment: This is very easy use RecycleView behalf ListView

Comment: i hope it will work for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/62011087/11554604

Answer (score 581, accepted):

For any Child view to scroll inside a ScrollView. Anything like ListView, RecyclerView, etc. You just have to replace ***ScrollView*** with ***[androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView)*** in your current xml and then magic happens.

Below is a sample xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Recycler View inside a Scroll View"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Below is a Recycler View as an example."
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/et_damaged_qty" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="This textview automatically goes below the Recycler View."
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

*Now you can get rid of all the ugly hacks you did to get around with nested scrolling.*

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me but I had to make some adjustments because the list items were complex views and I was using ExpandableListView: view = listAdapter.getView(0, view, listView); int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY); int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY); view.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

Comment: On Android 2.3 I get this behavior: After scrolling in the ScrollView, you need to single tap the ListView before you are able to scroll in the ListView again. Otherwise, it works well. I have not tested in other versions of Android yet. Anyone know how to get around this behavior? (I want to be able to immediately start scrolling in the ListView again instead of having to tap it first.)

Comment: @ArshadParwez, It is working fine. But now the problem is that if any item have content of more than one line, then it hides some part of listview. how to prevent this problem ?

Comment: I found this solution which works perfectly in my case, i.e. support list-items with variable heights -
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17503823/1433187

Comment: Please remove redundant ```requestLayout()``` – setLayoutParams method already does it.

Comment: FIX measuring
```view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));```

Comment: @ Arshu If I hard code the `list` values for child `ListView` the setted all list values are displaying in list.But in my code I am using a `web service` call to grab the values of list.If I use that `web service` returned list values only  `first` 0th position value is displayed in listview.The height for `listview` was set as single item height.the other values would be display only if we scroll the `ListView`.what I need is if I get a 5 values from web service call I have to show all 5 values in same time.

Comment: Great answer. But there is no need to call `listView.requestLayout();`

Comment: I need to do the same with gridview.. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Try using the header & footer view to inflate your views, instead of using GridView inside ScrollView

Comment: I had `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom` specified on `ListView`. So i have modified the code as `params.height = totalHeight + listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom() + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));` and that worked for me. Thanks !

Comment: Just as a side note, where you declare the method for your listview mattered for me.  I had to put it after i had already loaded the adapter and added items to it.

Comment: How can I do this for a recyclerView?

Comment: @summers : For RecyclerView you replace the ListView with recyclerView. I believe it should work.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I used 1.0 lib from grade, The measured height was calculated as zero with height = `wrap_content`. Here're the params `android:layout_marginTop="20dp"` `android:id="@+id/card_list"` `android:layout_width="match_parent"` `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` `android:background="@color/colorCardItemBackground"` `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` `android:focusable="false"`

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the row of the ListView is a RelativeLayout. Hasn't anybody else faced this problem?

Comment: you have to set adapter before the method is called

Comment: It works but now the list view height is double than the actual content

Comment: you do not even need this hack for sdk 21 and above, https://stackoverflow.com/a/6211286/2324552

Comment: Works fine for me, but when I touch inside the RecycleList to scroll, the Android scroll "bubbles" that appear at the top and bottom of the ScrollView now appear inside the RecyleView instead of the parent ScrollView.

Comment: For people like me, the dependency for NestedScrollView is Android.Support.v4

Answer (score 224):

The answer is simple and I am surprised it has yet to be answered here.

Use a `Header View` or/and `Footer View` on the list itself.
Don't mix a `ScrollView` with a `ListView` or anything that can scroll. It's meant to be used with headers and footers :)

Essentially, take all the content above your ListView, put it in another .xml file as a layout and then in code inflate it and add it to the list as a header view.

i.e.

```java
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
listView.addHeaderView(header);
listView.addFooterView(footer);
```

Comment: If you add header view, the position int param in onListItemClick will be +1. So you have to handle it. (the first item in list will have position 1, not 0)

Comment: I wish that there is a header for the ViewPager.

Comment: I wish there were a header for the GridView

Comment: Have you tried to put another `ListView` or `ScrollView` in Header or Footer?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar, yes and it behaves well. Try it.

Comment: I didn't understand how do I use this example. Do you have a extend example ?

Comment: plenty examples available on the web/so (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005549/how-to-use-addheaderview-to-add-a-simple-imageview-to-a-listview )

Comment: @HomayounBehzadian I think it does satisfy the OP's question, and also not a hack, but a feature of the ListView.

Comment: this approach goes well unless you need edittext in header. Edittext does not retain focus when present in listview

Comment: Keep in mind positions for the items after you add header. Header will be position 0 and items will start from position 1 in onItemClickListener

Answer (score 45):

I know it's been so long but I got this problem too, tried this solution and it's working. So I guess it may help the others too.

I add android:fillViewport="true" on the layout xml for the scrollView.
So overall my ScrollView will be like this.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView6" 
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

And it works like magic to me. 
the ListView that located inside my ScrollView expand to its size again.

Here is the full example code for the ScrollView and the ListView.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView6" android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        ....
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lv_transList" android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        ....
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It disables ListView scrolling behavior, therefore you can't scroll your list view if items are more than screen size.

Comment: It disable the scroll capabilities of ScrollView

Comment: This solution doesn't work because if the listview takes up the entire screen the elements below the listView are inaccessible

Answer (score 28):

**You Create Custom ListView Which is non Scrollable**

```
  public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {

            public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
                super(context);
            }
            public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
            }
            public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            }
            @Override
            public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
                    int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                            Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
                    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
                    params.height = getMeasuredHeight();    
            }
        }
```

**In Your Layout Resources File**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <!-- com.Example Changed with your Package name -->

                <com.Example.NonScrollListView
                    android:id="@+id/lv_nonscroll_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </com.Example.NonScrollListView>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lv_nonscroll_list" >

                    <!-- Your another layout in scroll view -->

                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

**In Java File
Create a object of your customListview instead of ListView like :** 
NonScrollListView non_scroll_list = (NonScrollListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_nonscroll_list);

Comment: This forces scrollview to scroll at the top of the listview. unexpected behavior

Answer (score 13):

Don't do anything in Parent ScrollView. Only do this to child ListView. Everything will work perfectly.

```
mListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
               int action = event.getActionMasked();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. It simple and smart. Just disable the scrollview when you are touching the listiview and enable it again when you lift your finger

Answer (score 10):

```
    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    // 获取ListView对应的Adapter
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0, len = listAdapter.getCount(); i < len; i++) { // listAdapter.getCount()返回数据项的数目
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0); // 计算子项View 的宽高
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight(); // 统计所有子项的总高度
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    // listView.getDividerHeight()获取子项间分隔符占用的高度
    // params.height最后得到整个ListView完整显示需要的高度
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

you can use this code for listview in scrollview

Comment: Will that disable the Listviews built in scroll?

Comment: This will also work for `ListView` inside `RecyclerView` to show more than then 1st element.

Comment: Thank you, this answer was very helpful. My issue was that I had a ListView inside a ScrollView, and when I updated the elements inside the ListView, the ScrollView would still have the same height. Meaning that the user was able to scroll down even though the ListView had less rows.

Comment: For anyone who spent a lot of time figuring out how to put a ListView inside a ScrollView(Not advised) because using linear layout would kill your UI, then this works fine but Would recommend you to dynamically add items in linearview

Answer (score 8):

This code will solve your problem if you have implemented just  a ListView in a code.

If you are using RelativeLayout as ListView child than this code return a NullPointerException here **listItem.measure(0, 0);**, because of RelativeLayout.And the solution is put your Relativelayout inside a LinearLayout and it will work fine.

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: If you have padding in your listview then you should add that too:-

int padding = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();

Comment: Yes, Relative layout creating problems while calculating height. Thanks for explaining Relative layout problem

Answer (score 8):

You may solve it by adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to your ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/white"
      android:fillViewport="true"
      android:scrollbars="vertical">

<ListView
      android:id="@+id/statusList"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:animationCache="false"
      android:divider="@null"
      android:scrollingCache="false"
      android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

</ScrollView>
```

before use that property, there was only one child of my list view is visible. after using that all the rows or child of list are visible.

Comment: Android:scrollingCache="false" is no more supported for new Android versions above v8.

Answer (score 5):

I'll leave it here in case anyone will face the same issue. I had to put a ListView inside a ScrollView. ListView with header was not an option by a number of reasons. Neither was an option to use LinearLayout instead of ListView. So I followed the accepted solution, but it didn't work because items in the list had complex layout with multiple rows and each listview item was of variable height. Height was measured not properly. The solution was to measure each item inside ListView Adapter's getView() method.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        . . .
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    . . .

    // measure ListView item (to solve 'ListView inside ScrollView' problem)
    view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can easy put ListView in ScrollView!
Just need to change height of ListView **programmatically**, like this:

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams listViewParams = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams)listView.getLayoutParams();
    listViewParams.height = 400;
    listView.requestLayout();
```

This works perfectly!

Comment: That's what [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19311197/1864167) does but instead of magically determining it's 400, it calculates the exact height. That way you don't have to guess.

Answer (score 5):

Done after lots of R&D:

**fragment_one.xml should looks like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewParent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dip" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/customView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Your other elements are here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Your Java class of FragmentOne.java looks like:**

```
private ListView listView;
private View customView
```

***onCreateView***

```
listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
scrollViewParent = (ScrollView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.scrollViewParent);
customView = (View)rootView.findViewById(R.id.customView);

customView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        scrollViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        // Disable touch on transparent view
                        return false;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        scrollViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        scrollViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        return false;

                    default:
                        return true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

My requirement is to include a ListView of equally-sized items within a ScrollView. I tried a few of the other solutions listed here, none seemed to size the ListView correctly (either too little space or too much).  Here's what worked for me:

```
    public static void expandListViewHeight(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null)
        return;

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    listView.measure(0, 0);
    params.height = listView.getMeasuredHeight() * listAdapter.getCount() + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem to the issue posed by the Original Poster - how to make the listview scroll inside the scrollview - and this answer solved my problem.
[Disable scrolling of a ListView contained within a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212890/disable-scrolling-of-a-listview-contained-within-a-scrollview/27818661#27818661)

I didn't call new fragments into existing layouts or anything like that, like the OP was doing, so my code would look something like this :

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="top" >

 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/fragment_dds_review_textView_label"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Reviews:"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/my_listView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Basically what I am doing is checking the length of the listview before I call it and when I call it I make it into that length. In your java class use this function:

```
public static void justifyListViewHeightBasedOnChildren (ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter adapter = listView.getAdapter();

    if (adapter == null) {
        return;
    }
    ViewGroup vg = listView;
    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, vg);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams par = listView.getLayoutParams();
    par.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(par);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

And call the function like this:

```
justifyListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listView);
```

The result is a listview with no scrollbar, the whole length of the listview being displayed, that scrolls with the scroll bar of the scrollview.

Answer (score 4):

Best solution is add this `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` attribute in child scrolling for example i have inserted this attribute in my `ListView` that is child of `ScrollView`. i hope this mathod works for you :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"/>
        <ListView
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" //add this only
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: BEST solution for listview with scrollview 
you should be the best answer   ......  THANKS

Answer (score 3):

As others had already mentioned, don't use ListView inside a ScrollView.

To workaround, you can use a LinearLayout, but to still keep things neat - populate your LinearLayout with an Adapter, same as you do with a ListView

You can use this class as a LinearLayout replacement that supports Adapters

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class AdaptableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

private BaseAdapter mAdapter;

private int mItemCount = 0;

private boolean mDisableChildrenWhenDisabled = false;

private int mWidthMeasureSpec;
private int mHeightMeasureSpec;


public AdaptableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public BaseAdapter getAdapter() {
    return mAdapter;
}

public void setAdapter(BaseAdapter adapter) {
    mAdapter = adapter;
    adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            updateLayout();
            super.onChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            updateLayout();
            super.onInvalidated();
        }
    });
    updateLayout();
}

private void updateLayout() {
    mItemCount = mAdapter.getCount();
    requestLayout();
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * set size for the current View
 */
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    mWidthMeasureSpec = widthMeasureSpec;
    mHeightMeasureSpec = heightMeasureSpec;

    removeAllViewsInLayout();
    for (int i = 0; i < mItemCount; i++) {
        makeAndAddView(i);
    }
}

private View makeAndAddView(int position) {
    View child;

    // Nothing found in the recycler -- ask the adapter for a view
    child = mAdapter.getView(position, null, this);

    // Position the view
    setUpChild(child, position);

    return child;

}

private void setUpChild(View child, int position) {

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = child.getLayoutParams();
    if (lp == null) {
        lp = generateDefaultLayoutParams();
    }
    addViewInLayout(child, position, lp);

    // Get measure specs
    int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(mHeightMeasureSpec, getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), lp.height);
    int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(mWidthMeasureSpec, getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), lp.width);

    // Measure child
    child.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

    int childLeft;
    int childRight;

    // Position vertically based on gravity setting
    int childTop = getPaddingTop() + ((getMeasuredHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - getPaddingTop() - child.getMeasuredHeight()) / 2);
    int childBottom = childTop + child.getMeasuredHeight();

    int width = child.getMeasuredWidth();
    childLeft = 0;
    childRight = childLeft + width;

    child.layout(childLeft, childTop, childRight, childBottom);

    if (mDisableChildrenWhenDisabled) {
        child.setEnabled(isEnabled());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: does this manage recycling? or is the adapter the responsible for recycling views?

Comment: I implemented this class quite some time ago, so I think for the purpose of dev.speed I didn't add recycling support.
As I see in the code right now class assumes that recycler is empty

Answer (score 3):

You can put all into linear layout. That is,  create linear layout and it will have 2 childs, scrollview and another linear layout. Give them layout weights and here you go :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="0.8">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/seTaskActivityRoot"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/taskName" />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/seTaskPrioritiesSP"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/taskTargetInNumeric" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/seTaskUnitsSP"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/newTaskCurrentStatus" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/addTaskCurrentStatus"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="0.2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/logList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This will mean the `ListView` won't scroll with the rest of the content. It will always occupy some of the screen regardless of whether the user scrolled up or down

Answer (score 3):

You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by ScrollView.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Answer (score 2):

Do NEVER put a `ListView` inside of a `ScrollView`! You can find more information about that topic on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20listview%20in%20scrollview). In your case, use a `LinearLayout` instead of the `ListView` and add the elements programmatically.

Comment: Oh Ok I see, Can i still use a similar concept of the adapter to fill the linearlayout?

Answer (score 2):

Update

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:gravity="top" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

to

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:gravity="top" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

The point here is you are trying to set height to 0dp (fixed)

Comment: That is so that the weights take effect on it.

Comment: Do you want the product image and lefttext view on upper side be scrollable ?  If so you should out these two item inside your Scroll view as I can see currently they are not

Comment: They are currently inside the scrollView as I programmatically add them to the linear layout which is inside the scrollview. If my logic is correct the linearlayout children should also be withing the scrollview.

Answer (score 2):

found a solution for scrollview -> viewpager -> FragmentPagerAdapter -> fragment -> dynamic listview, but im not the author. there is some bugs, but at least it works

```
public class CustomPager extends ViewPager {

    private View mCurrentView;

    public CustomPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (mCurrentView == null) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            return;
        }
        int height = 0;
        mCurrentView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = mCurrentView.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (h > height) height = h;
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    public void measureCurrentView(View currentView) {
        mCurrentView = currentView;
        this.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                requestLayout();
            }
        });
    }

    public int measureFragment(View view) {
        if (view == null)
            return 0;

        view.measure(0, 0);
        return view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}


public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;
    private int mCurrentPosition = -1;


    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);//or u can set them separately, but dont forget to call notifyDataSetChanged()
        this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(new FirstFragment());
        fragments.add(new SecondFragment());
        fragments.add(new ThirdFragment());
        fragments.add(new FourthFragment());
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
        if (position != mCurrentPosition) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
            CustomPager pager = (CustomPager) container;
            if (fragment != null && fragment.getView() != null) {
                mCurrentPosition = position;
                pager.measureCurrentView(fragment.getView());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

fragments layout can be anything

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="nevet.me.wcviewpagersample.FirstFragment">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#991199"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

then somewhere just

```
lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lv);
    }

    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null)
            return;

        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
                View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
            if (i == 0)
                view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight
                + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

using this ListView Worked for me

```
   package net.londatiga.android.widget;

      import android.util.AttributeSet;
      import android.view.ViewGroup;
      import android.widget.ListView;
      import android.content.Context;

   public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView
      {

    boolean expanded = false;

      public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context)
    {
    super(context);
}

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public boolean isExpanded()
{
    return expanded;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
    if (isExpanded())
    {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
{
    this.expanded = expanded;
}
}
```

and in xml

```
            <com.pakagename.ExpandableHeightListView
                android:id="@+id/expandableHeightListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </com.Example.ExpandableHeightListView>
```

and in MainActivity

```
  ExpandableHeightListView listView = new ExpandableHeightListView(this);
    listview=(ExpandableHeightListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableHeightListView);
   listView.setAdapter(adapter); //set your adaper
   listView.setExpanded(true);
```

[Refer This](http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/make-android-listview-gridview-expandable-inside-scrollview/) article  for more info and also to know how to keep gridview  inside scroll view

Answer (score 2):

- It is not possible to use Scroll-view inside List-view as List-view already has scrolling property.
- To use list-view inside Scroll-view you can follow these steps which worked for me :

  1) Create **NonScrollListView** java file that disable the default scrolling property of list-view. and code is below

  ```
  package your-package-structure;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.util.AttributeSet;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.ListView;

  public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {

    public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
              Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
      super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
      params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
  }
  ```

  2) Now create xml file which which has `NestedScrollView` and inside this use `NonScrollListView` for listing your items. This will make your entire screen to scroll with all the views.

  ```
          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:orientation="vertical">
              <ViewFlipper

                  android:id="@+id/v_flipper"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="130dp">
              </ViewFlipper>
              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                  android:text="SHOP"
                  android:textSize="15dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:padding="5dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>
              <View
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="1dp"

                  android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                  android:background="#ddd"/>
          </LinearLayout>
          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              >
              <com.abc.xyz.NonScrollListView
                  android:id="@+id/listview"

                  android:divider="@null"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:padding="8dp">
              </com.abc.xyz.NonScrollListView>
          </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"

              android:gravity="bottom">
              <include layout="@layout/footer" />
          </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>
  ```

  3) Now in java class i.e, home.java define `NonScrollListView` instead of `Listview`.

  ```
  package comabc.xyz.landscapeapp;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
  import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.ImageView;

  import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.Toast;
  import android.widget.Toolbar;
  import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
  ```

  public class home extends Fragment {
      int pos = 0;
      ViewFlipper v_flipper;

  ```
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);
      return view;
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      NonScrollListView listView = (NonScrollListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
      customAdapter customAdapter = new customAdapter(getActivity());
      listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
      listView.setFocusable(false);

      customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              Log.d("listview click", "onItemClick: ");
             /* FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new productdisplay());

              fr.putExtra("Position", position);
              fr.addToBackStack("tag");
              fr.commit();*/
              Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), productdisplay.class);
              intent.putExtra("Position", position);
              startActivity(intent);
          }
      });


      //image slider
      int images[] = {R.drawable.slide1, R.drawable.slide2, R.drawable.slide3};
      v_flipper = view.findViewById(R.id.v_flipper);
      for (int image : images) {
          flipperImages(image);

      }
  }

  private void flipperImages(int image) {
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
      imageView.setBackgroundResource(image);

      v_flipper.addView(imageView);
      v_flipper.setFlipInterval(4000);
      v_flipper.setAutoStart(true);

      v_flipper.setInAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
      v_flipper.setOutAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
  }
  }
  ```

  Note: I used `Fragments` here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here 's my answer. The method that fixes the ListView height is closed enough, but not perfect. In case that most of the items are the same height, that work well. But in case that's not, then there's a big problem. I've tried many time, and when I put out the value of listItem.getMeasureHeight and listItem.getMeasuerWidth into the log, I saw the width values vary a lot, which is not expected here, since all the item in the same ListView should have the same width. And there go the bug :

Some used measure(0 ,0), which actually made the view unbound, in both direction, and width run wild. Some tried to getWidth of listView, but then it return 0, meaningless.

When I read further into how android render the View, I realize that all of this attempt can't reach the answer that I searched for, unless these function run after the view is render.

This time I use the getViewTreeObserver on the ListView that I want to fix height, then addOnGlobalLayoutListener. Inside this method, I declare a new OnGlobalLayoutListener, in which, this time, getWidth return the actual width of the ListView.

```
private void getLayoutWidth(final ListView lv, final int pad){
        //final ArrayList<Integer> width = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        ViewTreeObserver vto = lv.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                lv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                //width.add(layout.getMeasuredWidth());
                int width = lv.getMeasuredWidth();
                ListUtils.setDynamicHeight(lv, width, pad);
            }
        });
    }

public static class ListUtils {
        //private static final int UNBOUNDED = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        public static void setDynamicHeight(ListView mListView, int width, int pad) {
            ListAdapter mListAdapter = mListView.getAdapter();
            mListView.getParent();
            if (mListAdapter == null) {
                // when adapter is null
                return;
            }
            int height = 0;


            int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width - 2*pad, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            for (int i = 0; i < mListAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = mListAdapter.getView(i, null, mListView);

                listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                //listItem.measure(UNBOUNDED, UNBOUNDED);
                height += listItem.getMeasuredHeight() + 2*pad;
                Log.v("ViewHeight :", mListAdapter.getClass().toString() + " " + listItem.getMeasuredHeight() + "--" + listItem.getMeasuredWidth());
            }
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mListView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = height + (mListView.getDividerHeight() * (mListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            mListView.setLayoutParams(params);
            mListView.requestLayout();
        }
    }
```

The value pad, is the padding that I set in ListView layout.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you don't want to use `addHeaderView` and `addFooterView`, e.g. when you have several lists, a good idea would be to reuse `ListAdapter` to populate a simple `LinearLayout` so there's no scrolling functionality.

If you already have a whole fragment derived from `ListFragment` and want to convert it to a similar fragment with simple `LinearLayout` without scrolling instead (e.g. to put it in ScrollView), you can implement an adapter fragment like this:

```
// converts listFragment to linearLayout (no scrolling)
// please call init() after fragment is inflated to set listFragment to convert
public class ListAsArrayFragment extends Fragment {
    public ListAsArrayFragment() {}

    private ListFragment mListFragment;
    private LinearLayout mRootView;


    // please call me!
    public void init(Activity activity, ListFragment listFragment){
        mListFragment = listFragment;
        mListFragment.onAttach(activity);
        mListFragment.getListAdapter().registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                refreshView();
            }
        });
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // create an empty vertical LinearLayout as the root view of this fragment
        mRootView = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        mRootView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mRootView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        return mRootView;
    }

    // reusing views for performance
    // todo: support for more than one view type
    ArrayList<View> mViewsToReuse = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<View> mCurrentViews = new ArrayList<>();

    // re-add views to linearLayout
    void refreshView(){

        // remove old views from linearLayout and move them to mViewsToReuse
        mRootView.removeAllViews();
        mViewsToReuse.addAll(mCurrentViews);
        mCurrentViews.clear();

        // create new views
        for(int i=0; i<mListFragment.getListAdapter().getCount(); ++i){
            View viewToReuse = null;
            if(!mViewsToReuse.isEmpty()){
                viewToReuse = mViewsToReuse.get(mViewsToReuse.size()-1);
                mViewsToReuse.remove(mViewsToReuse.size()-1);
            }
            final View view = mListFragment.getListAdapter().getView(i, viewToReuse, mRootView);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams oldParams = view.getLayoutParams();
            view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(oldParams.width, oldParams.height));
            final int finalI = i;

            // pass click events to listFragment
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mListFragment.onListItemClick(null, view, finalI, finalI);
                }
            });
            mRootView.addView(view);
            mCurrentViews.add(view);
        }
    }
```

You may also want to forward `onCreate`, `onPause`, `onResume`, etc. to the original fragment depending on your needs or try inheritance instead of composition (but override certain methods so original fragment is not actually attached to layout hierarchy); but I wanted to isolate original fragment as much as possible, because we only need to extract its `ListAdapter`. If you call original fragment's `setListAdapter` in `onAttach`, that's probably enough.

Here's how to use `ListAsArrayFragment` to include `OriginalListFragment` without scrolling. In parent activity's `onCreate`:

```
ListAsArrayFragment fragment = (ListAsArrayFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.someFragmentId);
OriginalListFragment originalFragment = new OriginalListFragment();
fragment.init(this, originalFragment);

// now access originalFragment.getListAdapter() to modify list entries
// and remember to call notifyDatasetChanged()
```

Answer (score 1):

found a solution for scrollview -> viewpager -> FragmentPagerAdapter -> fragment -> dynamic listview, but im not the author.

```
public class CustomPager extends ViewPager {

    private View mCurrentView;

    public CustomPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (mCurrentView == null) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            return;
        }
        int height = 0;
        mCurrentView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = mCurrentView.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (h > height) height = h;
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    public void measureCurrentView(View currentView) {
        mCurrentView = currentView;
        this.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                requestLayout();
            }
        });
    }

    public int measureFragment(View view) {
        if (view == null)
            return 0;

        view.measure(0, 0);
        return view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}


public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;
    private int mCurrentPosition = -1;


    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);//or u can set them separately, but dont forget to call notifyDataSetChanged()
        this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(new FirstFragment());
        fragments.add(new SecondFragment());
        fragments.add(new ThirdFragment());
        fragments.add(new FourthFragment());
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
        if (position != mCurrentPosition) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
            CustomPager pager = (CustomPager) container;
            if (fragment != null && fragment.getView() != null) {
                mCurrentPosition = position;
                pager.measureCurrentView(fragment.getView());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

fragments layout can be anything

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="nevet.me.wcviewpagersample.FirstFragment">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#991199"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

then somewhere just

```
 lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lv);
    }

    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null)
            return;

        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
                View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
            if (i == 0)
                view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight
                + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In xml:

```xml
<com.example.util.NestedListView
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/listview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:divider="@null"

                    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_delivery_type" >
                </com.example.util.NestedListView>
```

In Java:

```
public class NestedListView extends ListView implements View.OnTouchListener, AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    private int listViewTouchAction;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE = 99;

    public NestedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        listViewTouchAction = -1;
        setOnScrollListener(this);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, -1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int newHeight = 0;
        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter != null && !listAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                int listPosition = 0;
                for (listPosition = 0; listPosition < listAdapter.getCount()
                        && listPosition < MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE; listPosition++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(listPosition, null, this);
                    //now it will not throw a NPE if listItem is a ViewGroup instance
                    if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) {
                        listItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    }
                    listItem.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                    newHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
                newHeight += getDividerHeight() * listPosition;
            }
            if ((heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) && (newHeight > heightSize)) {
                if (newHeight > heightSize) {
                    newHeight = heightSize;
                }
            }
        } else {
            newHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), newHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, 1);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call this function after assign adapter to listview

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren
            (ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) return;

        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
                View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
            if (i == 0) view.setLayoutParams(new
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();

        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() *
                (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));

        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you what show all items in listView inside ScrollView use this code

```
val params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = listView!!.layoutParams
params.height = useitemsList.size * 200 //add static height 
listView!!.layoutParams = params
listView!!.requestLayout()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value of required height in a listview height attribute inside a parent scrollview. It will scroll along with other parents child item.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me ([link1](https://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/listview-inside-scrollview/), [link2](https://www.journaldev.com/10444/android-custom-listview-non-scrollable)):

- You Create Custom ListView Which is non Scrollable

  ```
  public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {

          public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
              super(context);
          }
          public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
              super(context, attrs);
          }
          public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
              super(context, attrs, defStyle);
          }
          @Override
          public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
              int heightMeasureSpec_custom = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                      Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
              super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
              ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
              params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
          }
      }
  ```
- In Your Layout File

  ```
  <ScrollView 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">

      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

          <!-- com.Example Changed with your Package name -->

          <com.thedeveloperworldisyours.view.NonScrollListView
              android:id="@+id/lv_nonscroll_list"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
          </com.thedeveloperworldisyours.view.NonScrollListView>

          <RelativeLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/lv_nonscroll_list" >

              <!-- Your another layout in scroll view -->

          </RelativeLayout>
      </RelativeLayout>

  </ScrollView>
  ```
- Create a object of your customListview instead of ListView like :

  ```
   NonScrollListView non_scroll_list = (NonScrollListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_nonscroll_list);
  ```

Answer (score -1):

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

    int action = event.getActionMasked();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: This is just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/27898262/191761

Answer (score -1):

### best Code

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btmlyt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/deshead_tv">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/des_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btmlyt"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="description"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question - there is no `ListView` at all in your code

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem for such a long time. Then I found a solution that worked for me.
Add a ListViewHelper java class. Here below is code for ListViewHelper.java

```
package com.molescope;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListViewHelper {
    public static void getListViewSize(ListView listView){
        ListAdapter adapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if(adapter!=null){
            int totalHeight = 0;

            //setting list adapter in loop tp get final size
            for (int i=0; i<adapter.getCount(); i++){
                View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, listView);
                listItem.measure(0,0);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            //setting listview items in adapter
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * 
    (adapter.getCount()-1));
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);

        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And after adding this java file, in your code wherever you are setting adapter to listview, right after that line add the code below:

```
  ListView myList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
  myList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>. 
  (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));
  ListViewHelper.getListViewSize(myList);
```

Pardon my english.

Comment: This is just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/18369577/191761

Answer (score -5):

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/listView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/36030926/191761