# ListView without Scrollbar to use in a ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I want to use a kind of `ListView` inside of a `ScrollView`. The list has a variable length, it is always possible to add/remove items. Is there an easy way to modify the default `Android` `ListView`, oder do I have to create a custom `ListView`?

Comment: add a listview in a scrollview is bad practice.What you want to achieve ?

Comment: create views in between scrollview by using a forloop

Comment: `ListView` is possible to add/remove items, and it can scroll by itself. So why do you want to have a new class that does the same thing?

Comment: Like others pointed out, this is very bad practice. Check out this answer by the creator of the listview widget and the discussion in the comments for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3496042/362298

Comment: I have a quite big vertical layout, inside which I want to have, among others, a list of `TextView`s. Of course I can put a lot of single `TextView` inside my layout, but for me that seems not to be very practical too.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView should expand to fill as much vertical area as it needs when contained in a ScrollView so you shouldn't have a problem.