# Scrolling of listView under a Scroll View is not happening

Tags: android

Hey I am using Listview under a scroll view. I want to scroll the ListView upto a position dynamically, am trying to do it with the following code but its not scrolling. can anybody please give me a solution.

listView.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
listView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);

Comment: Don't use listivew inside scrollview. ListView can scroll on it's own.

Comment: Try this....**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view

Comment: I have used the same method, but I want scrolling in the list view. please help me I need it

Comment: Does the list View scroll otherwise, at run time, when you scroll it using your figure?

Comment: no when i add a new item it should be automatically scrolled to that position

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `ScrollToPosition` try using the `setSelection` method of the listView

**example:**

```
listView.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: @user3571581 why put it in scroll view when listview scroll itself when its full

Comment: Its requirement of my app to put it in scroll view

Answer (score 0):

you should be use only listview and remove scrollview from its parent view and
 put above item of list view as header of listview and same 
below of listview set as footer of list view.

Comment: I can not change my scenrio right now. so please help me with the existed one

Comment: so you have to give a fixed (hard coded) height for list view params.

Comment: Yes i have given that, but my problem is m not able to scroll the list dynamically

Comment: because android confuse for take action on move of Scrollview or LstView ,so listview can't scroll as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do this just use this class

package com.whathappened.utils;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Helper {
//  public static void getListViewSize(DragSortListView myListView) {
//      
//      ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
//      if (myListAdapter == null) {
//          //do nothing return null
//          return;
//      }
//      //set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
//      int totalHeight = 0;
//      for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
//          View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
//          if(listItem!=null){
//          listItem.measure(0, 0);
//          totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
//          }else{
//              
//          }
//      }
//      //setting listview item in adapter
//      ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
//      params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
//      myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
//      // print height of adapter on log
//      Log.i("height of listItem:", String.valueOf(totalHeight));
//  }



    public static void getListViewSizeGroup(ListView myListView) {
        ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
        if (myListAdapter == null) {
            //do nothing return null
            return;
        }
        //set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
            View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
            if(listItem!=null){
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }else{

            }
        }
        //setting listview item in adapter
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        // print height of adapter on log
        Log.i("height of listItem:", String.valueOf(totalHeight));
    }
}


After setting the adapter just call Helper.getListViewSizeGroup(yourlistviewobject);
it will scroll..
```