# Have a view move down when more elements are added to ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

How can you have `ListView` fill the screen and also moving the view below with it until it reaches the bottom? For example, with the image below I would like for the 'Create' button to move down the screen when a new element is add and then when the button reaches the bottom then for the ListView to start Scrolling (with the create button still appearing on screen).

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        >

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/galleryList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lowerButtonLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#ffa8269f"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/button_button_bg_colour"
                android:onClick="addRow"
                android:text="Create"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Create a custom xml and add it as a footer of ListView. And you must set the ListView height to fill_parent.

Comment: @dpsingh - was hoping this could be done exclusively via layouts

Comment: The alternative is to use ListView inside ScrollView.

Comment: @dpsingh - its what i thought would work but didn't

Comment: Ok let me give u an example

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it can't be done only with xml file.

The easiest way to go would be to have 2 buttons. One in your main layout and one in your `ListView` (as a footer view for instance). Then depending on whether the `ListView` reaches a specific height, just set the visibility of one button to `View.GONE`.
If your cells have the same height, the calculation is pretty straight forward.

Do not use a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. It will ruin all the purpose of a `ListView` (being able to recycle cell).