# How to implement a ListView completely inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-xml

Here, I'm using a `listView` inside a `ScrollView`, everything is working fine but `listView` isn't displaying completely when I set its height`fill_parent`. So I've fixed its height and it doesn't look good when I change the android phone device. Can anyone help me in it?
 I'm posting my **xml** class too.

Demo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:text="@string/course_tracker"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_finishapp_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#E3E3E3" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="20" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#E3E3E3"
                android:text="" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/program_name" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#E3E3E3"
                android:text="" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#e9e9e9" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/colon"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#E3E3E3"
                android:text="" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="13"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/tv_program_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#E3E3E3"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#E3E3E3" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F9F9F9"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="20" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#E3E3E3"
                android:text="" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/program_description" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#E3E3E3"
                android:text="" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#e9e9e9" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/colon"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#E3E3E3"
                android:text="" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="13"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/tv_program_description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#E3E3E3"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#E3E3E3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#E3E3E3" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="20" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#E3E3E3"
                android:text="" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/course_name" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#E3E3E3"
                android:text="" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/semester" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#E3E3E3"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#E3E3E3" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@id/list_course"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout></ScrollView>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to put the `ListView` in a `ScrollView`. The `ListView` is already scrollable as-is.

Comment: why you want listview in scrollview,listview is already scrollable

Comment: I know it. But I have to add some tables inside it and all data is coming from web service  so I need to add `listView`.

Comment: I think what you want is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view

Comment: Sorry to say, your GUI design is much like web page design. This is not suitable for a common smart phone or a small tablet. The layout you have is barely manageable. For your sake or your project, you can separate the layouts onto separate files, more manageable.

Comment: I tried that too but no good result

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically set the height to ListView based on the list count,Like:

```
private void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        if (listItem != null) {
            listItem.measure(
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        }

        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

call above method after setting the adapter to the ListView,Like:

```
urListView.setAdapter(urAdapter);
setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(urListView);
```

Comment: Nothing is changed by using this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the headerView of the ListView: Put all the things you want above the list in the headerView and all the things you want below in the footerView. The listView will be shown at full height and the headerView is scrollable.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    mListViewHeaderView = initHeaderView(mListView, inflater);

    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mListView.addHeaderView(mListViewHeaderView, null, false);

    return view;
}


private View initHeaderView(ViewGroup container, LayoutInflater inflater) {
    View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_atm_details_header, container, false);

    // configure header view

    return headerView;
}
```