# How to keep Scroll from listview disabled until its parent ScrollView hits the top

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview

I Have a ListView inside a ScrollView and I want keep the listview scroll disabled until the ScrollView scroll position hits the top of the screen, then when scroll the listview until its top disable it again and enable its parent ScrollView scroll.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view

Comment: I have tesed it and working http://stackoverflow.com/a/32816390/3758898