# Setting ListView Height with ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have created List view with in Scroll View for that I have created one method to set the height of list view. like below - This method is working fine in API 22 but not in API 18(got null pointer Exception while running in API 18). please give me solution thanks

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView)
    {
        ListAdapter mAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

        int totalHeight = 0;
        System.out.println("Adapter "+mAdapter);

        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View mView = mAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            System.out.println("M View "+mView);
            mView.measure(
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),

                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

            totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();
            Log.w("HEIGHT" + i, String.valueOf(totalHeight));

        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight
                + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (mAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Show the stack trace if you get an exception.

Answer (score 4):

You should not put a ListView inside ScrollView.

Just refer the below results.

[ListView inside ScrollView is not scrolling on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android)

[Android list view inside a scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view)

Comment: Thanks Sridhar but, I don't want to scroll list view, I just want to scroll my whole page using Scrollview. and I want my List View like simple row

Comment: if i used this method

Comment: If i used above method my problem get solved in API 21,22 but not in API 18

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to put your listview inside the scrollview .By default listview has scrollview .

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error like you. And my solution is following as:

**1. Create a custom listview which is non scrollable**

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {

public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();    
}
```

}

**2. Use above custom class for xml file**

```
  <com.Example.NonScrollListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_nonscroll_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.Example.NonScrollListView>
```

It worked well on all OS-version for me.
Hope best for you.