# access of ListView inside scrollView

Tags: android, android-listview

I tried to search this question but no1 has answerd this, so here it is.
i am using a list view inside a scroll view.

when i am adding an onitemcliked listener to the listview it is not responding.
how to i get the listview access? i mean how do i get which position has been clicked. i know how it is normally done but inside a scroll view the listview is not reponding.

this is the code of adding onitemcliked listner to lisview.

```
 itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(cv, "position:"+arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
        }
    });
```

here is the xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="2dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/et_agent_details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Agent Details"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/linedivider" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Agent"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/login_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="LoginId"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:text="Route" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/route_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
          <requestFocus />
         </Spinner>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:text="Shop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvShopName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_shopaddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:text="Address : " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_no_order"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="No Order" />

</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/et2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Product Details"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/linedivider" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSearchBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" >


    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_SearchProduct"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Search" />

</LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/displayOrderTableView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="1"
    >

</TableLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_order"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Order"
        android:textAlignment="inherit" />
</LinearLayout>



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/underline" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_clear"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:textAlignment="inherit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_submit"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textAlignment="inherit" />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

pleasde help me i am stuck on this.. it might be a very silly solution. but please help me
thank u in advance.

Comment: Never use a ListView inside another scrollable view

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android list view inside a scroll view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused since that `ScrollView` is at higher level than the `ListView` in parent-child hierarchy. So that `ScrollView` can absorb touch events at its own level and does not pass them to its children. This results in the `ListView` will not get touch events at all and subsequently does not respond to `onItemClicked`.

[The solution is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19311197/1841194)