# In landscape mode, the ListView and WebView inside ScrollView not working as expected

Tags: android, android-listview, webview, scrollview, landscape

I am aware that I can't use `ListView` inside `ScrollView`, because `ScrollView` gets the focus in that case and `ListView` becomes non-scrollable. But I have a program that enables the scrolling of both `ListView` and `ScrollView`.(followed the great answer by [Mr. Arshu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19311197/4361127))

Structure of my `activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout    >

<ScrollView 
    android:fillViewport="true"  >

    <LinearLayout   >

        <TextView />

        <TextView  />

        <LinearLayout   >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"   />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"   />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:visibility="gone"  >

            <WebView />

            <ImageView   />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout   >

            <TextView  />

            <TextView />

            <TextView />

            <TextView />
            
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView> 

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <ImageView />

    <Button />

    <ListView
        android:visibility="gone"  />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This works perfectly when it is in portrait mode.Each `View` in `Activity` has its own purpose.

But I have two issues in `Landscape` mode.
[**I can't use `activity-land` as because I'm playing video in `WebView`**]

1. The `ListView` is visible when I click the button.

In `portrait` mode it display all items(ex: 10). When I change the mode to landscape the `ListView` doesn't scroll completely and it displays only 5 or 5 1/2 items.

2.`WebView` visibility is enabled on `Button` click.

If suppose I enable the webview in portrait mode and video starts playing, and in between if I change the mode to `Landscape` then the WebView disappears but video is not stopped. I can hear the video.

I've tried to control the `view` by using `savedInstanceState`.

Code snippet:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(savedInstanceState==null)
        {
            String uriPath = "http://player.vimeo.com/***/****";
            Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myWebView.loadUrl(uriPath);
        }else {
            Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            myWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
});
```

Images of `ListView`:

In portrait:

[image]

In landscape:

[image]

How to solve these two issues.

Kindly help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about u handle the orientation changes on ur own
I mean 
`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`
add the above attribute to `Activity` tag in Manifest file.

Comment: This solved `WebView` issue. But, `ListView` weird behaviour still persist.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I hope this touch listener for your view helps to solve your problem.

```
Yourview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        // Setting on Touch Listener for handling the touch inside
        // ScrollView
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of
            // child view
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```