# Endless ListView inside ScrollView

Tags: android

I want to add endless listView inside ScrollView but on ScrollChanged does not work

```
<ScrollView ..>
<EndlessListView ../>
</ScrollView>
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You shouldn't put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` because the `ListView` class implements its own scrolling and it just doesn't receive gestures because they all are handled by the parent `ScrollView`.

Comment: In my opinion, when you need to put a list view inside a scroll view, then you should re-think your design. However, if there is no way to change that, check [previous similar attempts](https://www.google.com.eg/webhp?q=listview%20inside%20scrollview).

Comment: @Aspicas Thanks in advanceو I know, I want any way to solve it.

Comment: @AhmedKhalaf Thanks in advance, But It is necessary to add list inside scroll .

Comment: @AhmedMohammed Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19311197/715593

Comment: Did You achieve to do this, if yes can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a listview in a scrollview, you have to re-implement a passive listview that does not handle its scroll. 
You'll have to check for children size and visibility, and do the recycling stuff yourself.
I did it, it is possible, but you should not go this way.

Comment: I did a passive listview that does not handle its scroll, i made the height of listView is the collect of height of all its children, the problem in endless scroll.
Can I check if scrollView at bottom?

Comment: What do you mean by endless scroll ? Is the list endless or the other content of the scrollview (below the list)?

Comment: The height of the custom view depends on what is inside, if the content changes, it is recalculated. This is how i do: i add the data, notify the adapter then the whole view adjusts itself depending on its content, and its visible children.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the code Jfreu :) ?