# Android Listview adapter in horizontalscrollview - Strange scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, android-adapter

I have a horizontal scrollview which contains two different listviews. 
When I perform my database requests and get the response I call

```
listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

on my ListView adapter which extends BaseAdapter class.
The listView is well updated but my main scrollView scrolls to the listView which is currently updating (on the right or left according which is updated before or after)

How can I prevent this strange behavior ?

Thanks

Comment: A scroll container view can not handle two more scroll container views, check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view