# ListView not Scrolling with parent LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, scrollview

I have a main ScrollView and then I have a child LinearLayout and that has ListView in it. I'm not sure why it is not scrolling. I read about how listview should not be inside scroll view, but I need my layout to scroll and then view the listview. I'm not sure if this is the proper approach. Please direct.

This works on my tablet with a large screen but not on my phone which has a smaller screen and you need to scroll to view the listview completely. The listview works if I use linear layout but then I don't see the listview completely because its on the bottom of the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/user_info"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:paddingTop="46dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/userTypeSpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/fname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="First Name"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" >
        <EditText android:id="@+id/lname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Last Name"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/staff_username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" >
            <EditText android:id="@+id/uname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="Username"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/staff_password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" >
            <EditText android:id="@+id/upassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/staff_email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" >
            <EditText android:id="@+id/uemail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="Email"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/staff_permissions"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/permission_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/addUserBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="@string/add_new_user"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android list view inside a scroll view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view)

Comment: You should not use ScrollView. Without ScrollView it will work.

Comment: It does work without it, but you cannot see it fully because the screen is small, thats why I was using scrollview to scroll down the layout

Comment: @user2698566 You can use NestedScrollView it supports both a nested scrolling parent and child http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

Comment: see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem i had. This is my code. Check it out.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/login_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="270dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/username_login" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/username_login"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/password_login" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Don't use scrollview as a parent. Just take scrollview inside parent layout i.e. LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

Comment: where is listview though?

Comment: i have not used listview in this code. But i'm giving you idea about scrollview how it works. Scrollview may be the reason your listview is not scrolling. Just try this once. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your ListView with LinearLayout and add same items(views) in this which you want to add in your listview