# RecyclerView inside ScrollView - ScrollView doesn't work

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm using the latest support design (`compile 'com.android.support:design:+'`) which from 23.2 should have fixed the issue with RecyclerView inside ScrollView.
**The RecyclerView and the ExpandableListView scrolling both work perfectly.** 
But when the ExpandableListView is too long and I want to be able to scroll the layout upwards so I could see the rest of it, the scrollview just doesn't work.

fragment :

```
 myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
    myRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager( mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false );
    layoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(recyclerDataList, getActivity());
    myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
```

xml:

```
 <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/headerText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="header text"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_below="@id/headerText"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


                <ExpandableListView
                    android:id="@+id/expandableList"
                    android:layout_below="@id/myRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:divider="1dp"
                    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                    android:groupIndicator="@null"
                    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:showDividers="middle" >
                </ExpandableListView>

            </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: that is not a duplicate. My recyclerview works fine, the problem is the scrollview tha thosts the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate listview height at run time, can not use listview or expendable listview inside scroll view like this.

[Android list view inside a scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view)

Answer (score 0):

You should do this way:

Implement **OnItemTouchListener** of RecyclerView and disallow parent touch event on `ACTION_MOVE`.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        int action = e.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                 recyclerView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
             break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                 recyclerView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
             break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                 recyclerView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);         
             break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :/

Comment: @BVtp, I have edited my answer, please check

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately it didn't help either.. I'm so frustrated.. Been on it for so much on it now:/