# Listview inside custom Scrollview

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to create a XML template such as the Google Play which implement the use of listview and scroll view as below

```
<custom scrollview>
    <imageview>
    <textview>
    <static listview> //list of comment
<custom scrollview>
```

The page is scrollable, but when user touch the listview area, the page become unscrollable, is there a way to make the entire page scrollable with the static listview in it?

Comment: Simply Don't use a ListView (scrollable element) inside a ScrollView (another scrollable view). If you want a static  ListView use LinearLayout . Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing/3496042#3496042

Comment: You can find a good solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19311197/1222099)

Comment: @MachoProgrammer - it's works, the custom scrollview was not needed after all, thank you, it help me alot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android list view inside a scroll view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view)