# how to display all items in the listview

Tags: java, android, xml-layout

I'm trying to include a ListView on a screen that already exists in my app.
My problem is that the ListView is displaying only the first item. I wish it were
displayed all the list.

Here is the my screen's xml:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/radialback"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:shrinkColumns="*">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@id/tabela_cuerpo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="0">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@id/tableRow0"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/tabela_cabecalho"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Corrida Recebida"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/tabela_conteudo"
                    android:paddingLeft="3.0dip"
                    android:text="Cliente: "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/txtPassageiro"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/tabela_conteudo"
                    android:paddingLeft="3.0dip"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/tabela_conteudo"
                    android:paddingLeft="3.0dip"
                    android:text="Distância: "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/txtDescricao"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/tabela_conteudo"
                    android:paddingLeft="3.0dip"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/tabela_conteudo"
                    android:paddingLeft="3.0dip"
                    android:text="Endereço:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/txtEndereco"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/tabela_conteudo"
                    android:paddingLeft="3.0dip"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/tabela_conteudo"
                    android:paddingLeft="3.0dip"
                    android:text="Valor: "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/txtValor"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/tabela_conteudo"
                    android:paddingLeft="3.0dip"
                    android:text="R$ 0,00"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/tabela_conteudo"
                    android:paddingLeft="3.0dip"
                    android:text="Telefone: "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/txtPtoReferencia"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2.0"
                    android:autoLink="phone"
                    android:background="@drawable/tabela_conteudo"
                    android:paddingLeft="3.0dip"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/pedidos_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@id/btnAceitar"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_green"
            android:text="Aceitar"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@id/btnVerMapa"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
            android:text="Ver Mapa"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@id/btnVerOrigemWaze"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
            android:text="Ver Local Origem"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@id/btnVerDestinoWaze"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
            android:text="Ver Local Destino"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@id/btnInformarTmpEstimado"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
            android:text="Tempo Estimado"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@id/btnClienteBordo"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
            android:text="Produto Já Recolhido"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@id/btnInformarValor"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
            android:text="Informar Valor"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@id/btnRejeitar"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_red"
            android:text="Rejeitar"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@id/btnCancelarAposAceitar"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_red"
            android:text="Cancelar Corrida"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@id/btnFinalizar"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
            android:text="Finalizar Corrida"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The screen is getting as follows:
http://anstaxi.com.br/android-screen-current-wrong.png

I need all the items are displayed.

### The code snippet is:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tela_corrida_multiponto);

String[] mobileArray =     {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max     OS X"};

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     R.layout.activity_listview_pedidos, mobileArray);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pedidos_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

-

Comment: As per layout you can not use ListView inside ScrollView. Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing

Comment: Also, post your adapter code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is using a listview inside a scrollview. Listview cant streatch itself inside the scrollview.

And after solving this issue. You will have problem with th scrolling (which one to scroll?)

But this link solves your problem:

[Android list view inside a scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view)