# Listview not working inside ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have created a listview inside scrollview, the list have started scrolling but linearlayout below listview does not appears on screen. have used custom adapter to fill list. Below is my code, please any body help me.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        tools:context=".Crew">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp"
                >

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/crew_list"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    ></ListView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="MESSAGE"
                        android:fontFamily="Myriad Pro"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textColor="#d0d0d0"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:gravity="top|left"
                        android:background="@drawable/textarealayout"
                        android:id="@+id/report_cabin_crew"
                        android:lines="3"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/greybox"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="SEND SMS"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:textColor="#0a3e8d"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="SEND MESSAGE"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttonlayout"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android list view inside a scroll view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view)

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40669978/6478047

Comment: you cant keep a scrolling element inside scroll view, so you need to expand listview completely inside scrollview

Comment: listview works fine but layout below list is not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have to scrolling layouts inside each other. When organize your layout you would realized that you can achieve the same behavior and look with one of them.