# Disabling the scroll of listview

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have created a listview inside scrollview. Atfirst it was not scrolling but when it started scrolling then layouts below list view started disappearing from screen. is there any solution to dynamically calculated he height of list view and assign it or is it possible that some how the scrolling of listvew is disabled so that only its items appear on screen like normal layouts or any tags and it does not scrolls???

Comment: please dont repeat questions

Comment: What do you actually want ? You have a scrollable listview and fixed bottom view which won't disappear while scrolling listview, is it ?

Comment: 20 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198861/listview-not-working-inside-scrollview

Answer (score 0):

ListView is deprecated. I would suggest you to use RecyclerView and add `nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` to your xml or call `RecyclerView.setNestedScrollEnabled(true)` if you want to wrap adapterview with a scroller. You can also try NestedScrollView for support compability.

Good luck

Comment: when did ListView get deprecated?

Comment: Since RecyclerView is out. Google suggests using it.

Comment: ok i know its better to use Recycler view , so list view is not deprecated i guess