# ListView inside ScrollView in android

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview, xml-layout

I'm having the `listview` inside the `scrollview` when I'm running the app list is scrolling limited to the first item. I think the Scrillview is overriding scrolling of listview here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/client_detail"
                android:text="CLIENT INFORMATION"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:background="@drawable/login_selector"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/client_detail">

                    /* HERE IS MY SOME OTHER LAYOUT */

                </RelativeLayout>
                <Button
                    android:text="CONTACT DETAILS"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/login_selector"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rl1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:id="@+id/contactDetails" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/contactDetails"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please need some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: use [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html).

Comment: You should use recyclerView and then set recyclerView.nestedScrolling(false);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view

Comment: I think your problem is when you start your activity your activity scroll to first item of list view, am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ExpandableHeightListView.

https://github.com/paolorotolo/ExpandableHeightListView

Comment: when I am using this view after expanding it is overlapping my above view

Answer (score 1):

when you use `ListView` with `ScrollView`, only one row of the `ListView` will be visible, so you have to set the height of ListView pro-grammatically depending on the elements inside `ListView`.You can make a function like this-

```
  public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }
    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    int totalHeight = 0;
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
        if (i == 0) {
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
        view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Then you use this method on the listview created-

```
  HourAdapter adapter1=new HourAdapter(getActivity(),day,start,end,x);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listview);
```

It works even if the rows of the `ListView` have variable height

Comment: Don't do this. This makes viewcaching of listitems impossible, resulting in unnecessary many inflated views, which leads to poor performance even for medium sized lists