# Android collapsing toolbar

Tags: android

Hey I want to full scroll my screen. What I have done is I have taken an expandable list view in my activity with some view-pager and other views. The expandable listview is scrolling perfectly to in its allotted space but what I want is my whole activity's layout should scroll from top to bottom, here is my xml code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context="websters.smartindiaserviceapp.Activities.CategoryDetails1">

        <include
            android:id="@id/tool"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />​
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/materialup.appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vpBanners"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/ciBanners"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:padding="1dip"
            app:fillColor="#ffffff"
            app:pageColor="#80cccccc" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lldesc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/main.collapsing"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvdesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="First Line"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            ​
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llservices"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/selecteditem"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lldesc"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvservices"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="Services"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/frstll"
            android:layout_below="@+id/materialup.appbar"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:childDivider="#f4f4f4"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:groupIndicator="@null" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="8dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
                app:backgroundTint="#1abc9c" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    So help to acheive proper scrolling in this layout file,,
```

This is the layout's screenshot I have acheived from this xml code.
Suggest me what I have to change to acheive proper scroll in this. Should I use a scroll view or coordinate layout and how? Help me out guys. I need smooth and proper scrolling in this activity's layout.

[image]

Comment: You can try this.  https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Comment: For proper scrolling you should use 'Scrollview'

Comment: Make coordinate layout as your parent layout..

Comment: Make coordinate layout as your root layout

Comment: abhay n ravish by doing so,,the expandable lv items goes on top of the viewpager,,n hides its items

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, But simple one is -
Use a Header View or/and Footer View on the list itself. 
Essentially, take all the content above your ExpendableListView, put it in another .xml file as a layout and then in code inflate it and add it to the list as a header view.

i.e.

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
expandableListView.addHeaderView(header);
expandableListView.addFooterView(footer);
```

Use this view as your header [image]

There is also **another** way using Scroll view and making expandableListView scroll disable .you can find [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19311197/5996106)

**Also** there is awesome tutorial here at [CoderzPassion](http://coderzpassion.com/android-expandable-listview-tutorial/).You will find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="websters.smartindiaserviceapp.Activities.CategoryDetails1">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/materialup.appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">


                <include
                    android:id="@id/tool"
                    layout="@layout/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/vpBanners"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/ciBanners"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    app:fillColor="#ffffff"
                    app:pageColor="#80cccccc" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lldesc"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/main.collapsing"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvdesc"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="First Line"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
                    ?
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llservices"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lldesc"
                    android:background="@color/selecteditem"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvservices"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="Services"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/frstll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/materialup.appbar"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ExpandableListView
                    android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:childDivider="#f4f4f4"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                    android:groupIndicator="@null" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:elevation="8dp"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
                    app:backgroundTint="#1abc9c" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try ..putting  `framelayout` as your parent instead of relative layout ..and end `nestedscrollview` brfore floating button