# Android Studio Looping LinearLayout with widget inside it

Tags: loops, android-layout, android-studio, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

[image]

I've tried this with custom listview but it gives me a lot of problem because I already have scollview. (as in the pic, listview inside scrollview)
I'm wondering if I could make a LinearLayout with imageview, textview for the name, and textview for the comments inside it and loop it so it will show all the comments like in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add what you want to a `LinearLayout`.

For performance reason this is not a good approach, because by this way you don't take advantage of views reclyclement. That means that if you add many much son views to your `LinearLayout` they are always loaded into memory and you should saturate it on poor devices.

You should migrate to the `RecyclerView` or in alternative you could keep your ScrollView and your ListView and read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view#answer-19311197)