# ScrollView applied only to LinearLayout child instead of the LinearLayout itself

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

I´m trying to make a scrollview but it is getting itself applied on the 2 lists I have in the LinearLayout, scrollview child. I want to be able to scroll, vertically, through the entire layout, but it only lets me scroll on the lists. What did I do wrong and could it be fixed?

Thanks in advance

content_habilitacoes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.luis.trabindividual.HabilitacoesActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_habilitacoes">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/content_habilitacoes_titulo_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/content_habilitacoes_titulo_1"
                    style="@style/contentMainTitle"/>

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ListaHab1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/content_habilitacoes_titulo_2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/content_habilitacoes_titulo_2"
                    style="@style/contentMainTitle"/>

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/ListaHab2"/>
            </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**How it is being displayed:**

[image]

Comment: I believe you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view

Comment: check nested scrollview...

Comment: Put your scroll view in the relative layout and make your relative layout as scroll view child instead of linear layout ................ and give match parent for relative layout