# ListView inside scrollView

Tags: android

I have an android layout which has a scrollView with a number of elements with in it. At the bottom of the scrollView I have a listView which is then populated by an adapter.

The problem that I am experiencing, is that android is excluding the listView from the scrollView as the scrollView already has a scroll-able function. I want the listView to be as long as the content is and for the master scroll view to be scroll-able.

i want to set the scrollView scroling if the listView has complete her scroling

@Gaurav Roy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view This could help you as he has the same problem like yours.

Comment: You can use ListView and RecyclerView with multiple views instead of these hacks.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android list view inside a scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to do anything special in layout.xml file nor handle anything on the parent ScrollView. You only have to handle the child ListView. You can also use this code to use any type of child view inside a ScrollView & perform Touch operations.

Just add these lines of code in your java class :

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.layout_lv);
lv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    // Setting on Touch Listener for handling the touch inside ScrollView
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    return false;
    }
});
```

If you put ListView inside a ScrollView then all the ListView does not stretch to its full height. Below is a method to fix this issue.

```
/**** Method for Setting the Height of the ListView dynamically.
 **** Hack to fix the issue of not showing all the items of the ListView
 **** when placed inside a ScrollView  ****/
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null)
        return;

    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int totalHeight = 0;
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
        if (i == 0)
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        view.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

To use this method just pass the ListView inside this method :

```
ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ls);
setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(list);
For using with ExpandableListView - credit Benny

ExpandableListView: view = listAdapter.getView(0, view, listView);
int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
view.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
```

For ListView with variable items height use the below link :

ListView inside ScrollView is not scrolling on Android

For Library to directly implementing in your code - credit Paolo Rotolo

https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/ExpandableHeightListView

Comment: why copy paste from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view?

Comment: just in case some one not see comment as they may get hidden as many people are going to comment.

Comment: Sory guys i forget the refer to
@Gaurav Roy

Answer (score 0):

Instead of embedding a `ListView` inside of a `ScrollView`, add the contents of the scrollview to a single viewgroup, then add those programatically to the top of the `ListView` with [addHeaderView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)).

For instance, have the root element of your layout be a `ListView`, and inflate a separate layout with the rest of the views via a LayoutInflater.  Then just pass that reference to the inflated view into the `addHeaderView` method.