# Android ListView inside ScrollView not proper

Tags: android, layout

I am sorry, I am new to android xml part. I am setting my listview which is inside scroll view to full screen but its frame is still small. How to resolve it? I have already set both width and height to "match_parent". Can someone help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.stacktips.speechtotext.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/row" >

        </ListView>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnSpeakContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#f5f5f5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSpeak"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_microphone_2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnSpeak"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/hint" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: ListView have default scroll then why you add scrollview?

Comment: Add `android:fillViewport="true"` this property to ScrollView

Comment: listview in scrollview isn't recommended, but if still you need this then you need to forcefully set height of list based on collective height of each cell. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/19311197/5110536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the ListView inside a ScrollView means  the ListView will not go to its full height. Take out the ScrollView surrounding the ListView and this should work for you :) ListView itself is scrollable.