# Listview inside scrollview does not scroll in lanscape mode

Tags: android, listview, android-wrap-content

I have to generate a dynamic `listview` in android. The `listview` is put inside a `scrollview` because I have other content too to display above the `listview`. Something like this :
[image]

Down part is the listview which is dynamically added. This all comes fine on a portrait mode on Samsung note5 but when I change the screen orientation to landscape the listview does not scroll. This could be because I have given wrap-content for the listview.

Please check my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@color/gray25"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:background="@color/light_blue"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp">
        <!--Top header-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/topheader"
                android:background="@drawable/dashboard_button"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp">

            </LinearLayout>
        <!--middle portion-->


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/RFIDList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/dashboard_button"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/_50sdp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
<!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp">               
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I cannot give fixed height to the listview because its items are generated dynamically. I tried to find the solution and also tried changing my listview to recyclerview but did not work. but Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Android list view inside a scroll view](//stackoverflow.com/q/18367522)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android list view inside a scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `RecyclerView` use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` and set

`recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` after setting layout manager

for `ListView` see my answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40669978/6478047)

Comment: Looks like perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use below method after `listView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);`
as
    setlistViewHeight(listView,context);

Your problem will be solved.

```
public static void setlistViewHeight(ListView listView, Context context) {

    ListAdapter myListAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

    if (myListAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {

        View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, listView);
        if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup)
            listItem.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        int listViewWidth = screenWidth - 65;
        int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listViewWidth,
                View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        listItem.measure(widthSpec, 0);

        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount()));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```