# How do I make a RelativeLayout scrollable?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add a scrollView to my relative layout without changing main relative layout.

I've tried to add a scrollView in different places of my code in xml but it does not work, also the position of the elements becomes mixed up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/green"
tools:context="com.example.ahmedashrafhamza.GP.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_send_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bubble"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:minLines="3"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"



        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can somebody assist?

Comment: can you put <LinearLayout> over <ListView>?
Then do not have to impose scrolls.

Comment: You need a scrollview for that, it is as simple as that, i am providing a sample code

Comment: Wrap it in a ScrollView

Comment: I did  what you said but then there is compilation error in layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android list view inside a scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view)

Answer (score 0):

Make the `scrollView` the parent view, then have the `RelativeLayout` as a child view. It will work.
Remember that the scrollView does not support sibling views.

**EDIT**
The question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view)

Comment: I did  what you said but then there is compilation error in layout

Comment: I just noticed the listView. Having two vertically scrolling elements in one layout file is not allowed, due to issues that might arise will confusing layouts.

This problem has been answered and solved already.

Comment: where are the two scrolling elements?

Comment: The scrollView and the listView

Comment: Try the link I shared. Someone asked the same question as you years ago, and it has been answered.  Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on "layout"-> New -> Layout Resource File
2. enter file name as sample
3. type root element as ScrollView
4. link this layout file to any activity.

And in layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />


        <View
        android:id="@+id/Separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_below="@id/Heading"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ParaOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Separator"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="1)  fvfvfvfvfvfvfv fvfvfvfvfvfvfvfvvfvfv vfvfvfvfvfvfvfvfvfv "
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ParaTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ParaOne"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="2) fvvfvfvfv fvfvfvfvfvfvfv fvfvfvfvfvfvfvfvvfvfv "
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ParaThree"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ParaTwo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="3) fvvfvfvfv fvfvfvfvfvfvfv fvfvfvfvfvfvfvfvvfvfv "
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ParaFour"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ParaThree"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="4) fvvfvfvfv fvfvfvfvfvfvfv fvfvfvfvfvfvfvfvvfvfv "
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

1. Goto text mode and copy below relative layout as it is
2. Goto Design mode and you should see scrolling relativelayout if you scroll the mouse over layout
3. Or you can copy-paste whole code as it is in your existing layout file just for checking how scroll works
4. But you have to unlink any java class or code associated with that layout just for testing

Try it and let me know.

Comment: @A.Hamza, should i give a sample project code with this..?