# How can I allow scrolling of multiple ListViews on a single Activity?

Tags: java, android

I've created a CV building app and the last Activity displays all the information in the form of ListViews. Each ListView has layout_height=wrap_content  which means that once the user enters more than one previous job, the data falls off the screen and is unscrollable.

I've already tried to limit the space used by the ListView, making it's own data scrollable however this doesn't look right on the screen. I'd much prefer to have all data displayed and the whole screen scrollable. Any suggestions?

Also, I don't want the user to have to move across to other Activities to view the data they've entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ScrollView, it can be solved.
In your layout.xml file, try to wrap all list views with ScrollView like this.

```
...
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </ListView>

    <ListView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </ListView>
   ...
</ScrollView>
...
```

If you can't solve your problem, please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view).

Comment: Thanks friend. I tried this earlier and for some reason it's working now. :)