# How to fix ListView inside ScrollView?

Tags: android, xml, layout, interface

I need to put a ListView inside ScrollBar. I know there is other question about this theme but the answers are very complex and bad.

The ListView doesn't show all its elements, only the first one.

The main structure of my relevant code:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                ....MORE ELEMENTS....
                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    ></ListView>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to set layout_height="match_parent" in the scrollview and add "android:fillViewport=true" to the scroll view

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view

Answer (score 0):

Put your `ListView` in a separate `LinearLayout` parent or you can add it in a separate .xml file according to your choice and add

```
 android:fillViewport="true"
```

in your scrollview, like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!....MORE ELEMENTS....>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Where I have to put  `android:fillViewport="true"`, in the AndroidManifest?

Comment: In ScrollView Tag **<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true">**

I've edited my answer as well