# Cannot see ListView at bottom of Screen in Landscape Mode

Tags: listview, android-listview, android-xml, screen-orientation

I have a LinearLayout `android:id="@+id/content_frame"` nested inside a DrawerLayout `android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"`.

At the top of the LinearLayout are ImageViews, TextViews, Buttons, Switches etc. These are nested in a selection of horizontal and vertical LinearLayouts. All good so far.

At the bottom of the LinearLayout is a ListView which is also nested in its own a LinearLayout. So my Layout looks like the below. (Gravity, Padding etc. parameters removed below to save space).

All is good in the world in Portrait Orientation, but once I change to Landscape the screen height is too small on many devices to see my ListView in the bottom half of the screen.

I have tried wrapping it all in a ScrollView, but then my ListView wont auto size to `fill_parent` and remains one item tall, and with ScrollView in Landscape Orientation it wont let me scroll the ListView at all.

**Could someone please recommend a way to allow me to see my ListView at the bottom of the screen and Scroll it in both Portrait and Landscape modes?**

Thank you in advance!!

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView />

                    <ImageView />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText />

            <Spinner />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button />

            <Button />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ProgressBar />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button />

            <Switch />

        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/myTeamsListView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner"
                    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/myTeamsListViewcontent"
                    android:isScrollContainer="false"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:scrollingCache="false"
                    android:smoothScrollbar="false"></ListView>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:onClick="onSwitchChange"
        app:headerLayout= "@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@xml/drawer_view" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Achieved this through a combination of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36030926/5696328

This:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27898262/5696328

And this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26998840/5696328