# How can I put a listView inside a scroll view on android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, scrollview

I can't scroll the list view that is inside the scroll view.I tried using nested scroll view but it still dosen't work. hope I'll get some help here :)

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, It is not recommended to use this technique. You can use your ListView with Headers and Footers to eliminate the use of scrollView.

If you are still bent on using ListView inside ScrollView(Not recommended). Here is a hack:
[Android list view inside a scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view)

TLDR;
The shortest & easiest solution for any ChildView to scroll inside a ScrollView. Anything like ListView, RecyclerView, etc. You do not have to do anything special in code.

Just replace ScrollView with android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView in your current xml and then magic happens.