# How to add profile information in android navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation

Hi I am working with android. I added android navigation drawer as in g mail to my app successfully.Now I want to add a profile picture view as in the image . I tried it in list item. but I want more space as just like in the image..How can I do this ??? Please help me I am new to android [image]

here is my code for list item

```
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1), true, "22"));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1), true, "50+"));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom listview?

Comment: I also need to implement this.Any reference example ravi? and have you done!?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464416/use-custom-layout-in-navigationdrawer-with-header-and-list

Comment: just read this post its can help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464416/use-custom-layout-in-navigationdrawer-with-header-and-list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464416/use-custom-layout-in-navigationdrawer-with-header-and-list)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Firstly I'd say you need to rank your information in order of importance. The users name being, presumably, the most important and therefore what they need to see to tell them

a) they are logged in and

b) which account they're logged in with.

for more follow this link 
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/44776/navigation-drawer-with-my-account-entry

Answer (score 9):

I Also Solve this Problem.Just Modify some of Code in XML And Java.

Change code follow below code...... I think solve your problem

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerll"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/list_item_title"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pic_pic" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/drawer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@color/list_item_title"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Shohel Rana"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="test@gmail.com"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/list_item_title"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And Java code Just Added below code::::

final boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerll);

here drawerll means Total linear Layout.
and 
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerll);

and close Drawer Layout....

Here Total Java Code:

```
package by.fitbody;`enter code here`

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import by.fitbody.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import by.fitbody.model.NavDrawerItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    // private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    private Context con = null;

    LinearLayout drawerll;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        con = this;

        final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
                R.color.customRed)));
        bar.setIcon(R.drawable.articles_05);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        // navMenuIcons = getResources()
        // .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        drawerll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerll);

        makeSlideList();

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.main_menu, // nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                    // accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                    // accessibility
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /*
     * make slide list
     */`enter code here`

    private void makeSlideList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0]));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1]));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2]));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3]));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4]));
        // What's hot, We will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5]));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6]));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7]));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8]));

        // Recycle the typed array
        // navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        final MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbarmenu, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(
                R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /*
     * fo(non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)
     * 
     * 
     * for search bar
     */

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Handling intent data
     */
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            final String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Log.e("Search text is ", query + "");

            /**
             * Use this query to display search results like 1. Getting the data
             * from SQLite and showing in listview 2. Making webrequest and
             * displaying the data For now we just display the query only
             */
            Toast.makeText(con, "Query is " + query, 1000).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_rate:

            Toast.makeText(con, "rate button is clicked", 1000).show();

            return true;

        case R.id.action_best:

            Toast.makeText(con, "Best button is clicked", 1000).show();

            return true;

        case R.id.action_liked:

            Toast.makeText(con, "liked button is clicked", 1000).show();

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items

        /*
         * active those code if you want to hide options menu when drawer is
         * opened.
         */
        final boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerll);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_best).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_liked).setVisible(!drawerOpen);

        menu.findItem(R.id.action_rate).setVisible(!drawerOpen);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:

            fragment = new ArticleFragment(position);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ArticleFragment(position);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ArticleFragment(position);
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new ArticleFragment(position);
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new ForumFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            final Intent i = new Intent(con, FitnessClubActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new ArticleFragment(position);
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new ArticleFragment(position);
            break;
        case 8:
            fragment = new AboutUsFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerll);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {enter code here`
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

I Think this would Solve your Problem:

I've just modified this sites code:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: I get the next exception: "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams" ... how I can solve this?

Comment: Yes, but I had some modifications and I got that error ... I have already solved it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: My problem was I closed NavigationDrawer with ListView and I had to put the main LinearLayout instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a custom View in NAvigatindrawer not only a listvew. So create a LinearLayout with your pic and a listview and you get the result.

Have a look at this SO Thread:
[Is it possible to use something other than a listview as sliding drawer in drawerlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738595/is-it-possible-to-use-something-other-than-a-listview-as-sliding-drawer-in-drawe)

Have fun ;)

Comment: Then how can I add this layout into drawer..if you dont mind can you show me an example please

Comment: have a look at the second answer in the other so thread "This will work ..." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738595/is-it-possible-to-use-something-other-than-a-listview-as-sliding-drawer-in-drawe

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information you can Use FB parse which gives you a very easy way how to add those apis and fetch the details easily , they have simple documentation step by step have a look

You can read about this here : https://www.parse.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using

```
mDrawerList.addHeaderView();
```

where you need to add a View object

Comment: could you give more specific information about the parameters we should pass to this mehtod?tanx

Comment: @ArefAnafgeh you need to add View Object. 
For more info 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005549/how-to-use-addheaderview-to-add-a-simple-imageview-to-a-listview