# 2 elements layout and listview inside scroll view

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to scroll a parent container having linear layout and listview as its child layouts. The problem is that ListView scroll doesnt work inside ScrollView, i have tried this but didnt work.

[Android list view inside a scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view)

I want to make it look like as if the "simple layout" is ListView's 0th item. So simple layout scroll with the listview rows. I think its doable by using different layouts inside getView in List Adapter but simple layout will going to have 2 dropdowns and button which will be used to control the below list just like a filter. So i think its not a good idea to do this as all the click handlers for dropdown and button will be inside getView.

[image: two layouts inside once scrollable container]

Comment: Why not add the simple layout as a ListView header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you are not approaching it right.
All you want to do is to add a header to the list.

This can be done easily by the ListView object itself.
Try this:
[How to use addHeaderView to add a simple ImageView to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005549/how-to-use-addheaderview-to-add-a-simple-imageview-to-a-listview)

Answer (score 3):

- You Can use [ListView HeaderView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnG5ZIVfki8) As mentioned above,
- Also
  You can put them both ( ListView & Simple Layout ) inside a parent LinearLayout
  Then include the parent LinearLayout inside a parent ScrollView